# How can I load Geospatial RDF in Virtuoso?

Tags: geospatial, virtuoso, geosparql

Sorry for noobish question. I want to know what kind of format (syntax) a geospatial RDF should have so I can load it into Virtuoso (Open Source) and do a GeoSPARQL query over it. I found a very small and simple geospatial RDF and wanted to load it into VOS, but it gave me an error as the result:

> `Unable to load RDF graph <something> from <geospatial data name> with Content-Type 'application/rdf+xml': 42000: RDFGE: RDF box with a geometry RDF type and a non-geometry content`

Edit: 
I uploaded RDF without any instances and VOS loaded it successfuly. But when I add the instance into it, the error pops. Here the whole RDF i use is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:sf="http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#"
    xmlns:geo="http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#"
    xmlns:my="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#">
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#PlaceOfInterest">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource= "http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#Feature"/>
</rdfs:Class>
<rdf:Property rdf:about="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#hasExactGeometry">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#hasGeometry"/>
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#hasDefaultGeometry"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:about="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#hasPointGeometry">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#hasGeometry"/>
</rdf:Property>
<!-- Instance -->
<my:PlaceOfInterest rdf:about="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#F">
    <my:hasExactGeometry rdf:resource="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#FExactGeom"/>
</my:PlaceOfInterest>
<sf:Point rdf:about="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#FExactGeom">
    <geo:asWKT rdf:datatype= "http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral">
        <![CDATA[ <http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84> Point(-83.4 34.4) ]]>
    </geo:asWKT>
</sf:Point>

</rdf:RDF>
```

VOS Version is 07.20.3217. What's wrong?

Comment: this might be better suited for http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That sounds like an error in the content of the RDF/XML... Maybe try some additional sample data, from other sources.

Comment: I uploaded RDF without any instances and VOS loaded it successfuly. But when I add the instance into it, the error pops. Here it is:
<my:PlaceOfInterest rdf:about="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#F">
 <my:hasExactGeometry rdf:resource=
 "http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#FExactGeom"/>
</my:PlaceOfInterest>
<sf:Point rdf:about="http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#FExactGeom">
 <geo:asWKT rdf:datatype=
 "http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral">
 <![CDATA[
 <http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84>
 Point(-83.4 34.4)
 ]]>
 </geo:asWKT>
What's wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional details.

Comment: This question is discussed in the GIS community [Link to OP in GIS Community](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230999/loading-geospatial-rdf-in-virtuoso)